# why label is display inside select box?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation, material-design, material-ui

why my select box label display inside the `select` box  .Take a example i am not using react -material-validator .it show like this
https://codesandbox.io/s/5vr4xp8854

when i tried to  validate my select box using react-material-ui-form-validator plugin my label come inside the select bx why 
here is my code
**plugin:** 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-material-ui-form-validator
https://codesandbox.io/s/38x8q8zpm5

[image]

Secondly when I submit my label is not display in red color why ?

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ValidatorForm onSubmit={() => {}} className="" autoComplete="off">
        <FormControl>
          <InputLabel shrink={true} htmlFor="age-simple">
            Age
          </InputLabel>

          <SelectValidator
            required
            value=""
            name="name"
            displayEmpty
            validators={["required"]}
            errorMessages={["this field is required", "email is not valid"]}
            inputProps={{
              name: "age",
              id: "age-simple",
              shrink:true
            }}
            SelectProps={{
              displayEmpty: true,
              shrink:true
            }}
            input={<Input id="age-simple" />}
            className=""
          >
            <MenuItem value="">
              <em>None</em>
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
          </SelectValidator>
        </FormControl>
        <Button type="submit"> submit</Button>
      </ValidatorForm>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like [Material UI FormValidator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-material-ui-form-validator) package simply takes a `label` property. You should remove

```
<InputLabel htmlFor="age-simple">
   Age
</InputLabel>
```

and add the `label` and `InputLabelProps` with shrink: true (as discussed in the limitations [Here](https://material-ui.com/demos/text-fields/#limitations) ) properties for your `SelectValidator`, for example:

```
<SelectValidator
   required
   label="Age"
   InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true }}
   value=""
   name="name"
   .......
```

This will also fix your label not appearing in red when the user hits submit without a selection.